# What are alternatives to the GetShortPathName function?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm looking for a function which can return the 'short' (8.3 notation) path for a given 'long' path. However, the [GetShortPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364989(VS.85).aspx) function (which seemed like a perfect fit) doesn't work for me since it requires thata file with the given long path exists already.

What other options do I have for computing the 8.3 path for a given long path?

Comment: the short name *depends*. Note those ~1, ~2's at the end of the filenames? Say you have two files `notsoshortfilename.txt` and `notsoshortfile.txt`, one of them is going to be named `notsos~1.txt` and the other `notsos~2.txt`. Which one gets which name? It depends on which names are taken when the file is created and its short name generated.

Comment: @jalf: That's what I gathered. I thought the algorithm which inspects the list of files in a given directory and then computes a new 8.3 file name which doesn't clash with any of the existing names would be available in a dedicated function. In particular, in a function which doesn't require that the file identified by the given path exists already.

Comment: The problem is that such a function would be inherently racy.  You couldn't guarantee that a particular short name wouldn't be taken in between the program calling the function and using the result.

Comment: Also due to some ridiculous Microsoft patent claim, some non-MS devices and operating systems write random junk for the 8.3 name to avoid stepping on patent toes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the file does not exist, it does not have an 8.3 name. The 8.3 name is created when the file is created. You can of course get the 8.3 pathname for the directory it's in using `GetShortPathName` on the directory itself, if you need that.

Regardless, this is 2010. It's really backwards to be using 8.3 names for **anything**.

Comment: I've actually used GetShortPathName to pass unicode path names to old libraries that blow up on UTF-16, it's still backwards, but it shows there's still a use.

Answer (score 2):

Try PathGetShortPath function.

Comment: +1 This has the added bonus of not requiring the path to exist to get a DOS path back.  Just a note: PathGetShortPath works on a wide, or utf16, string, so you will need to encode and then decode if you're working with utf8/ascii strings.  Since I was calling this function from C# I had to use the native WideCharToMultiByte to get the correctly decoded string, since C# was handling the encoding incorrectly.